# How to separate input streams - simple client-socket program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ftp, client-server

Client:

```
public class Client {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private OutputStream os;
    private BufferedInputStream bis;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private BufferedOutputStream bos;
    private int bytesRead;
    private int current;

    public Client(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }

    public void menu() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("1. CONN: Connect to Server");
            System.out.println("2. UPLD: Upload file");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
            String input = br.readLine();
            out.write(input);
            out.flush();
            if(input.equals("UPLD")){
                sendFile();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendFile() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter filename");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileName = br.readLine();
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        if(!myFile.exists()){
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist!");
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("File has been found!");
        }
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); //get the output stream of the socket
        dos.writeInt((int) myFile.length()); //write in the length of the file
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile); //create an inputstream from the file
        OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); //get output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192]; //create buffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len); //write buffer
        }
        in.close(); //clean up
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Host:");
        String h = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter port:");
        String p = br.readLine();
        Client ftp = new Client(h,Integer.parseInt(p));
        ftp.menu();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private OutputStream os;
    private BufferedInputStream bis;
    private FileInputStream fis;

    private String fileName = "SampleFile.txt";

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            String input;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            input = in.readLine();
            if (input.equals("UPLD")) {
                //System.out.println("activate uploadFile");
                //System.out.println(input);
                receiveFile();
            } else System.out.println("Why?");
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public void receiveFile() throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); //get the socket's input stream
        int size = dis.readInt(); //get the size of the file.
        InputStream inp = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("copy.txt"); //stream to write out file
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192]; //buffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inp.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len); //write buffer
        }
        out.close(); //clean up
        inp.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter the port you wish to bind to: ");
        String port = br.readLine();
        server.start(Integer.parseInt(port));
        System.out.println("Connected to client; awaiting operation request");
    }
}
```

How can I make it such that the client input, assigned to String input via br.readline() is FIRST sent to the server so the server knows to call the receiveFile() method, and THEN the sendFile() method is called in the client. I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working now - I perform flush() after input is written to the PrintWriter, so why can't the server receive this first, and then receive the file? Currently, when I print the server's BufferedReader it has the input AND the file contents on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Its the nextline char makes issue in client side.
Append with UPLD\n & write it.
You are reading  input = in.readLine(); @server side

```
public void menu() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println("1. CONN: Connect to Server");
        System.out.println("2. UPLD: Upload file");
        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
        String input = br.readLine();
        out.write(input+"\n");
        out.flush();
        if(input.equals("UPLD")){
            sendFile();
        }
    }
}
```